# Add AdSupport Framework to an Xcode project with CLI command or Ionic configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

I am currently working on an ionic application whose targetted platform is ios. I use Firiebase Analytics plugin and [this requires to add AdSupport Framework](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport?hl=uk) into Xcode build configuration.

I would like not to add this manually as it is documented because it breaks my continous delivery process. Is there a way to programitcally add a framework to the build with a CLI or ionic configuration ?

Comment: yes you add in plugin.xml file

Comment: i dont think possible in config.xml file which correct way

Comment: can you see addSupport.framework file in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation([1](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html))([2](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework)) It is not possible to specify that in a project  `config.xml`. However you can specify which framework library you need for ios in `Plugin.xml` when you write a new plugin.

This is that `framework` property :

> Identifies a framework (usually part of the OS/platform) on which the
>   plugin depends.

```
// In Plugin.xml
<framework src="libsqlite3.dylib" />
<framework src="social.framework" weak="true" />
<framework src="relative/path/to/my.framework" custom="true" />
<framework src="GoogleCloudMessaging" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.2.0" />
```

I found a plugin that allow that [here](https://github.com/NestedLooper/cordova-plugin-ios-frameworks) and [I forked it](https://github.com/tbetous/cordova-plugin-ios-framework-adsupport) for my special needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Open plugin.xml(in firebase analytics plugin folder) and below line under ios :

```
<platform name="ios">
   <framework src="pointToYour/File.framework" embed="true" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly, this only works when you create your own plugin. This does not work in the config.xml of my project as it said in the doucumentation : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework. I had to use a plugin that allow to do that : https://github.com/NestedLooper/cordova-plugin-ios-frameworks that I forked for what I wanted.